# How to run CLion with msys2 on windows

Tags: clion, msys2

How to run clion with msys2 on windows? I have set the toolchain, but when it can't find `<socket.h>`.[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33969803/704292 This may help you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Run the following command

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

And install all (default).

Comment: There are 17 sub options to pick from, which one is the right one for winx64?

Comment: @Dariusz Sorry, I haven't developed on Windows for a long time.

Comment: @Dariusz you probably just want to install all of them

Comment: With my case, I got 19 members in group `mingw-w64-x_86_64-toolchain` and I chose `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`.